# Protractor throws StaleElementReferenceError when using element.all to iterate through a table

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have protractor test which will iterate on a table with 6 columns. I am iterating on the table using element.all and then search for specific text in first column. If matches, check the status in 6th column, if it is set to Activate, click the matched row which will take it to another page, perform an operation, come back to table page, reiterate on the same table and check for that specific text and validate the final status to be Activate again.

The test runs fine but fails with below error.

```
StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

element.all(by.css('tbody tr')).each(function(item){
    var count=0;
    var pass=0;
    //TEST VALUES BELOW
    var appNameCreated="Test App 534";
    //TEST VALUES ABOVE
    item.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function(appname){
        if(appname==appNameCreated){
            console.log(appname,appNameCreated);
            item.element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText().then(function(result){
                pass += 1;
                console.log(result);
                if (result=="Activated"){
                //if (result==data.resultSubmit){
                    item.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).element(by.css('a')).click().then(function(){
                    browser.sleep(4000);
                    });
                    element(by.id("btnTab3")).element(by.xpath('span')).click();
                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]'))),15000);
                    element(by.id("button-basic")).click();
                    element.all(by.css('ul[class="dropdown-menu"]')).each(function(item1){
                        item1.element(by.css('li:nth-child(7)')).element(by.css('a')).click();
                    })
                    element.all(by.css('tbody tr')).each(function(item2){
                        item2.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function(appname1){
                            if(appname1==appNameCreated){
                                item2.element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText().then(function(resultFin){
                                    console.log(resultFin);
                                    browser.actions().mouseMove(item2.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)'))).perform();
                                    expect(resultFin).toBe(data.resultFinal);
                                })
                            }   
                        })
                    })
                }           
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: please, format your code nicely first

Comment: Hope this helps - @LuninRoman

Comment: The stale element reference is due to the DOM of the HTML page changing when you click the link to another page. You cannot continue your loop as your initial element are now 'stale'. If you post some of the html for the table we can likely propose a solution